# Delphi all-in-one .exe storage

Tags: windows, delphi

I write a very tiny TSR program (`passwordmanager.exe`) and have two very small `files of records`.

Actually i save all files (exe, data) to one USB-Stick the user always transports, wherat the data contains sensible data.

Is there any technique to modify the internal resource of the `passwordmanager.exe` itself that is currently running? As far as i know the exe is copied to the RAM, so the `passwordmanager.exe` may have no write lock and i am able to let the `passwordmanager.exe` grow if the user enters new Passwords.

**Why do i think this may work?** Years ago i had a MSDOS program who asks for the password but unfortunatelly the user has forgotten his password. As i printed the contents of the MSDOS-Program to the console the user luckily found his password in the machine-code!

Question: How can i store the two very small files of records into the `exe`?

Comment: I don't find storing data to the binary itself *more secure* anyhow. The user may still notice that the file is growing and copy it as well as they could if it was in a separate file. Also you may upset some antiviral programs.

Comment: Its crypted, its ok. Yes the antiviral program will get upset, i dont care.

Comment: Its not a full duplicate, i will never find a answer in the duplicate you suggest.

Comment: @PeterRader You can't write to a running executable. That's what the other question and answers should make clear.

Comment: @Jens, that's a different question, [`this one`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11319805/960757) is a bit closer (Remy has covered also the case of running application in his answer). Peter, also if you're going to install your app into folder like program files, you'll need to elevate your process on systems with enabled UAC, which might be annoying.

Comment: @TLama yea, this is a question more like mine. I think what Jens has been marked as a duplicate is a *you-cant-*answer in my eyes.

Comment: @TLama Oh, you are right. I missed to specify the conditions of the Security-Rules the user has. I edited the question, the situation is more like a poor-man's dongle.

Comment: @PeterRader Why don't you / your customer encrypt the USB drive? There are lots of solutions for that.

Comment: @Jens This is a good idea, so we can use .txt-files. But encrytion is not the problem. Or do you have a new idea?

Comment: @PeterRader What is the actual problem then? If you encrypt the drive or the data (you could just encrypt the .txt file using a standard encryption method) the sensible data is only visible to the user that has the decryption key. Are you trying to implement some sort of steganography?

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff The question is: *How can i store the two very small files of records into the exe?*

Comment: @PeterRader The answer to that is: "As long as the executable is still running, you can not."

Answer (score 3):

In your comments you wrote *"Yes the antiviral program will get upset, i dont care"*
Well, if you don't care that your program *might* be blocked. *and* you have write permissions to that USB device, I can think of a pattern like this:

Copy your `running.EXE` (`Application.ExeName`) to a `patch.EXE` (via `CopyFile`)  - or generate that `patch.EXE` from a Resource (Antivirus would NOT like this!).

`running.EXE` Execute/Create new process `patch.EXE` with parameters e.g.
`patch.EXE /update /your_record_parameters /pid:running_process_id`

`patch.EXE` will start and check for `/update`; Signal `running.EXE` to shutdown; Wait for it to shut down; patch `running.EXE`; Execute `running.EXE /patch_done`; Shut down itself.

Finally,  `running.EXE` could clean up now by checking the `/patch_done` and Delete  `patch.EXE`

Answer (score 1):

On NTFS, you could use alternate file streams:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105763

(I remember round about when Win2K first came out, seeing a magazine article (UK PC Pro) which showed how to use Notepad to store a secondary stream in an .Exe and was astonished that any OS with pretensions of security would provide this facility, but there you go.)

A tool for viewing them:

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/alternate_data_streams.html

Comment: Not a good idea, they easily get lost and even Microsoft stopped supporting AFS for metadata in Windows Explorer since Vista.

Comment: I can use 7zip to view it too i think.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/05/01/10299322.aspx

Comment: @Jens Mühlenhoff:  I wasn't meaning to suggest it was a good idea (see parenthetical bit I've added to my ans), just that it exists.

Comment: @MartynA You should have pointed out the disadvantages, but you didn't, so I filled that gap.

Comment: @Jens Mühlenhoff: Fine, but if every SO answer included every conceivable health warning ... anyway, correspondence closed.

Comment: Alternate file streams in executables have no security implications.

Comment: Also a USB-stick is mentioned, are those limited to FAT32?

Comment: @Stijn Sanders:  ISTR that some early sticks didn't support it, but I just re-formatted a FAT32 one to NTFS, copied the D7 IDE onto it, did an fc and it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any technique to modify the internal resource of the passwordmanager.exe itself that is currently running?

No there is not. When a process is started its executable file is locked exclusively and so cannot be modified.

Comment: What is a possible dos attack?

Comment: A DoS attack is a *Denial of Service* attack.

Comment: @peter I know what DoS means. I just didn't see the relevance in the original, now deleted comment. I also don't see how DOS TSR's relate to Windows. Or did you mean something else with that acronym. Your downvote appears to be poorly cast.

Comment: TSR do not work on DOS only, it works on Windows,Linux,Mac too. Assume i am administrator, like to format the USB-Stick: If a user run the exe-file, the formatation will be denied - a *Denial of Formatation*-Attack, you know?

Comment: @Peter TSRs don't exist on Windows. The answer I wrote is technically accurate. I can't understand your downvote.

Comment: I followed this tutorial and it works great (looks strange, i have a .exe in the services-tab in the task-manager) http://www.nova.pc.pl/modtsr.pdf

Comment: @PeterRader Technically there is no such thing as a "terminated" process that is still running, in the tutorial you linked to the author describes a normal Windows GUI application with a hidden main window.

Comment: @Peter There are no TSRs on Windows. What I state in my answer is accurate.

Comment: But i can delete the exe while its running. I can even unplug the stick, but i cant save then. Do you like to have the exe? I will share it on github if you like. Anyway, the question is different: *How can i store the two very small files of records into the exe?*

Comment: I answered the quoted part of your question. That you downvoted and started talking about tsrs on windows suggests that you aren't really here for advice. Why would I continue to try to help you?

Comment: You answered "DO can i store the two very small files of records into the exe?" not "HOW can i store the two very small files of records into the exe?".

Comment: Never mind. You seem to know better than me. I'm sure you can solve the problem yourself. With your windows tsr.

Comment: Even windows8.1 works great.